# Global sections of projective rational curve are constants: easy proofs wanted

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, schemes, projective-varieties

Suppose $C$ is a projective rational irreducible dimension $1$ Noetherian
scheme over field $k$ and I would like to collect some of most
usual common preferably as elementary as possible ways to prove that the $k$-space $\Gamma(C, O_C)$
of global sections of $C$ is one dimensional, that is equals
$k$.

One appoach I learned from Ravi Vakil's FOAG notes is to use the
extension Theorem 16.5.1 for nonsingular curves. It states that
if we have a rational map $X \dashedarrow Y$ where $Y$ is projective
scheme and $X$ a nonsingular curve then the rational map extends
to regular map $X \to Y$.

In our case $C$ is rational, so $k(C)=k(t)=K(\mathbb{P}^1_k)$ and
we obtain a birational map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to C$ which is welldefined
on dense open sets of both schemes and by extension Theorem this map
etends to a regular map. $C$ is irreducible and the image of $C$ is dense therefore
we get inclusion
$\Gamma(C, O_C) \to \Gamma(\mathbb{P}^1, O_{\mathbb{P}^1}) =k$.
Since $\Gamma(C, O_C) \neq 0$, we conclude $\Gamma(C, O_C)=k$.

This proof uses extension Theorem as technical ingredient and I think
that there are much easier ways to show $\Gamma(C, O_C)=k$. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need a projective assumption otherwise $Spec(k[x])$ is a counter example.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis:Yes, for $\Bbb{P}^1$ I assume that we know that $\Gamma(\Bbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^1})=1$. I'm going to discuss global sections of $C$ and use here in this 'complicated' argument the map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to C$ to compare global sections of $C$ with already known of $\Bbb{P}^1$ (which as you said can be calculated by Cech coho)

Comment: @DavidLui: Thanks,you are right. I have to assume $C$ to be projective, thank you. +1

Comment: A couple of minor quibbles about the argument: the map you get from the rationality assumption is birational, not just rational; I think you have assumed as much implicitly, but it should be stated. Also, "the map is dense" does not make strict sense because denseness is a property of a subset in a topological space, not a map; you want something like "the image of the map is dense."